# point-to-point at IP layer

Tags: ip, point-to-point, 5g

I was reading one of 5G standards specifying signalling transport https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/138400_138499/138472/15.06.00_60/ts_138472v150600p.pdf and noticed (section 6):

> The IP layer of F1-C only supports point-to-point transmission for
> delivering F1AP message

Does this mean that the underlying link for delivering these F1AP messages can't be shared by any nodes except the two participating in transmission, e.g. A <-> B? In other words we can't expect to have a switch or router in between A and B which would attempt to forward/intercept these messages to other nodes connected to switch/router. Is that an assumption?

Comment: Switches are transparent devices that do not get involved with IP. You could have a point-to-point IP connection between two devices with a switch between them.

Comment: But if it is L3 switch (aka router?), theoretically it could mangle packets and redirect them to other ports. In such a case, it would not be p-to-p link anymore? I feel that _point-to-point_ simply is equivalent to _unicast_.

Comment: A layer-3 switch is first a layer-2 switch. An IP point-to-point link will connect on the same layer-3 network, not passing through a layer-3 (SVI) interface on a layer-3 switch, only using layer-2 on the switch.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the underlying link for delivering these F1AP messages can't be shared by any nodes except the two participating in transmission, e.g. A <-> B? In other words we can't expect to have a switch or router in between A and B which would attempt to forward/intercept these messages to other nodes connected to switch/router. Is that an assumption?

No. Point-to-Point simply means it is a one-to-one relation, regardless of routing and switches.

Point-to-Point traffic can still be intercepted.